# How to reference audio file for Watson audio-to-text API

Tags: ibm-watson

This is a total **Watson** newbie question, according to its doc,

```
curl -X POST -u "{username}":"{password}"
--header "Content-Type: audio/flac"
--data-binary "@audio-file1.flac"
--data-binary "@audio-file2.flac"
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?timestamps=true&word_alternatives_threshold=0.9
```

Question is, where are these two audio files located exactly?  How do I reference my own audio file instead of them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Never mind.  The file seems to need to be in the same directory.

Comment: I attempted to use my IBM bluemix id and pwd but received http error code of 403, "Forbidden".  What needs to happen to access this API effectively?  Thanks.

Comment: Never mind, it's resolved.